# Ionic Android Appication GIT INIT ERROR(EXIT CODE 128)

Tags: git, ionic-framework, exit-code

I'm currently working on a android application to help my dad with his job, but when starting with `ionic start FirstApp blank` the command is unable to continue due to a fatal error [image: displayed here]

I'm on Windows 10, my node version is v6.11.2, npm version is 3.10.10, ionic v3.7.0, git version 2.14.0.windows.1.

PS: I alredy have a SSH key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to create a new project in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. This is definitely not a good place to do that, Windows won't let you.

Make a new directory somewhere else first, and create your project there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found out by myself in the hard way, thanks anyway!